# facing this error while importing gdal-->>DLL Load Failed: The Specified Module Could Not Be Found

Tags: python, gdal, osgeo

I'm new to python and I am getting the

> "ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be
>   found."

when importing the module `" gdal "`.

I tried different ways to get rid of it and come up with something but none of them worked properly as I expected .

I should notice that when I tried to check that if it's installed or not ,results  were telling it's done. I thought there'd be some dependencies maybe.

Any Suggestion ??

```
from osgeo import gdal
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-61e0eefce4de> in <module>()
----> 1 from osgeo import gdal

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py in <module>()
 19                 fp.close()
 20             return _mod
---> 21     _gdal = swig_import_helper()
 22     del swig_import_helper
 23 else:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\osgeo\__init__.py in 
swig_import_helper()
 15         if fp is not None:
 16             try:
---> 17                 _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, 
description)
 18             finally:
 19                 fp.close()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py in load_module(name, file, filename, 
details)
241                 return load_dynamic(name, filename, opened_file)
242         else:
--> 243             return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
244     elif type_ == PKG_DIRECTORY:
245         return load_package(name, filename)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py in load_dynamic(name, path, file)
341         spec = importlib.machinery.ModuleSpec(
342             name=name, loader=loader, origin=path)
--> 343         return _load(spec)
344 
345 else:

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```